# Is it possible to tell cassandra to run a query only on the local node

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I've got two nodes that are *fully* replicated. When I run a query on a table that contains 30 rows, cqlsh trace seems to indicate it is fetching some rows from one server and some rows from the other server.

So even though all the rows are available on both nodes, the query takes 250ms+ rather than 1ms for other queries.

I've already got consistency level set to "one" at the protocol level, what else do you have to do to make it only use one node for the query?

```
select * from organisation:

 activity                                                                                        | timestamp    | source       | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+----------------
                                                                              execute_cql3_query | 04:21:03,641 | 10.1.0.84 |              0
                                                 Parsing select * from organisation LIMIT 10000; | 04:21:03,641 | 10.1.0.84 |             68
                                                                             Preparing statement | 04:21:03,641 | 10.1.0.84 |            174
                                                                   Determining replicas to query | 04:21:03,642 | 10.1.0.84 |            307
                                                                 Enqueuing request to /10.1.0.85 | 04:21:03,642 | 10.1.0.84 |           1034
                                                                   Sending message to /10.1.0.85 | 04:21:03,643 | 10.1.0.84 |           1402
                                                                Message received from /10.1.0.84 | 04:21:03,644 | 10.1.0.85 |             47
 Executing seq scan across 0 sstables for [min(-9223372036854775808), min(-9223372036854775808)] | 04:21:03,644 | 10.1.0.85 |            461
                                                              Read 1 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 04:21:03,644 | 10.1.0.85 |            560
                                                              Read 1 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 04:21:03,644 | 10.1.0.85 |            611

………..etc….....
```

Comment: Related to, but not a duplicate of, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586927/delete-rows-stored-on-a-particular-node

Comment: - Are the 2 nodes similar in terms of hardware? Is the load on both similar (check system metrics)
 - Can you issue nodetool status, nodetool info and nodetool netstat on both nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there was a bug in Cassandra versions 2.0.5-2.0.9 that would make Cassandra more likely to request data on two nodes when it only needed to talk to one.

Upgrading to 2.0.10 or greater resolves this problem.

Refer: [CASSANDRA-7535](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-dev/201411.mbox/%3cCAAam9svqJ0p6utEkqofQFFha=QSM+bfQTmpbD1=uD5MbE4zeDA@mail.gmail.com%3e)

Comment: +1 Good find.  I was wondering about this one, as your coordinator should have been able to figure out which node was "closest," and stick with it (unless it became unreachable).